# How to read cell from data frame in a for loop where the frame name increases with the loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Sorry for the terrible title. First post here, and new with R.

I am trying to import data from multiple CSV files, extract a single row from each CSV to individual data frames then make a new data frame for a specific value from each initial data frame. I hope this makes sense.

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
# Take downloaded IFD csv's for 15 points, extract 1% AEP, 6 hour rainfall depths.
 
files <- list.files(path = "C:PATH")

for (i in 1:length(files)){                     # Head of for-loop, length is 15 files
  
  assign(paste0("data", i),                     # Read and store data frames for row containing 6 hour depths
         read.csv2(paste0("C:PATH", files[i]), sep = ",", header = FALSE, nrows = 1, skip = 26))
  
}

#final value in data frame, position [1,9] is the 1% AEP depth for 6 hours. Extract all of these values from the initial 15 data frames into new dataframes.


for (i in 1:15) {
  
    SixHourOnePercentAEP[i] <- data[i][1,9]
  
}
```

In the last argument, an error is returned trying to call data[i][1,9] since dataframe[x,y] is trying to find a cell where the iteration of the i occurs. Looking for a way around this.

Comment: R is not a macro language. And it does not automagically append file extensions. You are also going to need directory separators.

Comment: @Slurpied Exactly what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to create dataframes such as data1, data2, etc for each corresponding file. Then you are trying to access the i-th dataframe with the syntax data[i].

But that's not how it works. "data" is not an array of dataframes, but instead you have different variables named data1, data2, etc. What you need is to access given variable by name. You can do it this way:

```
for (i in 1:15) {
    SixHourOnePercentAEP[i] <- get(paste0("data",i))[1,9]
  
}
```

The get() function gets a variable whose name has been passed as a character argument.

I found however your code extremely inefficient. Why gather all the entire dataframes beforehand, when the only thing you need is one cell from each one? You should rewrite your first loop to extract the desired value from the dataframe immediately then store it, discarding the rest of the data right away if I understand you purpose correctly.

Comment: Thanks mate, that was exactly what I was looking for. I agree the code is inefficient, however I could not get the first loop to get the specific cell I require. Will look back over it now to attempt this a second time. Thanks again!